# TypeError issue importing hdbscan

Tags: python, hdbscan

```py
Python 3.11.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jun 10 2023, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hdbscan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\natha\anaconda3\envs\bertopic\Lib\site-packages\hdbscan\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .hdbscan_ import HDBSCAN, hdbscan
  File "C:\Users\natha\anaconda3\envs\bertopic\Lib\site-packages\hdbscan\hdbscan_.py", line 40, in <module>
    FAST_METRICS = KDTree.valid_metrics + BallTree.valid_metrics + ["cosine", "arccos"]
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
>>>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

i tried reinstalling conda and python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think this is related to https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/597

Comment: @ewokx thank you so much!!! I installed a previous version of scikit learn and now its fixed!

Answer (score 3):

It was an issue with the new version of scikit-learn, I installed a previous version and now it works. More information about the issue can be find in the `hdbscan` repo: [github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/597](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/597)